# Sharpen PDF while preserving bookmarks and searchable text

Tags: windows, pdf

There's a certain PDF of a book that I'm using, which contains bookmarks for all the relevant chapters and sub-chapters as well as searchable text (probably OCR'ed). Unfortunately, the text looks a bit faded, making it quite difficult to read.

I'm looking for a way to sharpen and color-balance the pages of the book, while preserving the bookmarks structure and the OCR'ed text. I am coming up blank.

I've tried using irfanview (batch converting to TIFF while applying the relevant filters, then batch converting back to PDF), but this breaks the OCR and the bookmarks. I'd be happy for any advice.